# Why A simple method having two arguments is not working in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

My controller:

```
public class AjaxController : Controller
{
    private readonly IGenerationUnitMobileService _generationUnitMobileService;
    public AjaxController(IGenerationUnitMobileService generationUnitMobileService)
    {
        _generationUnitMobileService = generationUnitMobileService;
    }
    public IActionResult MobileExistToAnotherGenerationUnit(String mobile, long generation_unit_id)
    {
        //ViewBag.Result =  _generationUnitMobileService.MobileExistToAnotherGenerationUnit(mobile,generationUnitId);
        return View();
    }
}
```

And My view file is very simple:

```
@model PgcgSms.WebSite.Models.GenerationUnitMobileViewModel

@{

    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Ajax.cshtml";
}
@ViewBag.Result
```

This is so much straight forward. But when I browse at: `http://localhost:57216/Ajax/MobileExistToAnotherGenerationUnit/01719393045/1`

I am getting the following error message:

```
This localhost page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:57216/Ajax/MobileExistToAnotherGenerationUnit/01719393045/1
Search Google for localhost 57216 Ajax Mobile Exist To Another Generation Unit 01719393045
HTTP ERROR 404
```

I checked the view file and spellings several times. Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Do you have a route defined for it? Does `.../Ajax/MobileExistToAnotherGenerationUnit?mobile=01719393045&generation_unit_id=1` work?

Comment: Yes. This is working. But why I have to configure route. any route like: /ControllerName/ActionName/param1/param2/param3/... should work.

Comment: What are your route definitions? If you have just the default, then that will allow only 3 segments (controller/action/id). If you want `../Ajax/MobileExistToAnotherGenerationUnit/01719393045/1` to work, then you need to define a route definition for it.

Comment: The custom route should follow convention like this: `{controller}/{action}/{mobile}/{generation_unit_id}`. Also that the custom route should be in upper order against default one, because MVC routing evaluates from top (most specific) to bottom (most general).

Answer (score 0):

In the RouteConfig.cs file you will have to specify the default route.
For Example:

public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

```
        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "AjaxController", action = "MobileExistToAnotherGenerationUnit", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, the default route should not be adjusted like that, because it may affect other routes. Use a custom route and put that on top of default one.